# How to get an even drip without Mr. Coffee filtration disks

Tags: coffee-machines

I’ve been trying to figure out why our coffee has been very weak despite double the amount of grounds used compared to the old coffee maker we had. We received a new coffee maker at Christmas. Both the old and new coffee makers are Mr. coffee brand. The new coffee maker however lasted a couple of months before it started producing really weak coffee. I think I figured out today that the problem is that the filtration disk needs to be replaced every month. The disk we have is the one that came with the coffee maker at Christmas a few months ago. When I look at the grounds, there are primarily two depressions where it looks like most of the water is dripping and those depressions line up with bulges in the filter above, so I think that a disk replacement should produce a more even drip. However, I am not interested in buying disks to replace every month. We already have filtered water in our house. So I’ve been wondering if there is a filtration disk replacement that can be a permanent solution to producing an even drip. Perhaps a metal or plastic piece with holes in it similar to what I see on our old coffee maker where the drips came from.

I tried searching for such a product, but could not find one. Does anyone have another solution for this issue? Any tricks?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about filtering the water, you may cut round pieces from any paper filter and place them on top of the coffee pile in the basket before each brew. This should help to distribute hot water on the coffee pile.

Keep in mind, that this may be more expensive than using the regular filter as the cut pieces of water filter could be used once.